# MockMVC not returning any value when given JWT token in JUnit Test

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, mockito, jwt

```
@Test
public void getUsers_Success() throws Exception {

            when(userRepository.findAll()).thenReturn(userList.getUsers());

            String token = TokenAuthenticationService.createToken("me@me.com");
            assertNotNull(token);

            RequestBuilder request = MockMvcRequestBuilders
                    .get("/api/v1/users")
                    .header("Authorization", "Bearer "+ token);

            MvcResult result = mockMvc.perform(request)
                    .andExpect(status().isOk())
                    .andExpect(content().json(usersJson))
                    .andReturn();

            result.getResponse().getContentAsString();
        }
```

Here is the token generation

```
public static String createToken(String username) {
        String jwt = Jwts.builder()
                .setSubject(username)
                .setExpiration(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + EXPIRATIONTIME))
                .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS512, SECRET)
                .compact();

        return jwt;
    }
```

When I run this test, the response is always empty. And then the json parsing fails because the response is empty.

Answer (score 0):

The method `signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS512, SECRET)` is deprecated and will be removed in future releases. You should use :

```
signWith(SECRET, SignatureAlgorithm.HS512)
```

I suppose SECRET is a String object => you need to generate secret key based on your secret:

```
signWith(Keys.hmacShaKeyFor(SECRET.getBytes()), SignatureAlgorithm.HS512)
```